# How to query snmp trap through system floating IP?

Tags: system, snmp, standby, heartbeat

I have written a snmp-agent, and it can run in system (rhel5). 
By querying oid from snmp client, it will get snmp trap. 
But my problem is: if there are two servers(one is stand-by system, one is active system),If I query snmp trap by **floating IP**, I will get no snmp trap. **That is, I have to query by the true(active) IP, not floating IP.**

My question is : is there a way to query snmp trap through floating IP? How to configure my snmp-agent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your snmp agent to INADDR_ANY (0.0.0.0) instead of the actual IP address.

Comment: bstpierre, I am not sure if I bind my snmp agent to INADDR_ANY(0.0.0.0), could I communicate with my snmp agent well? I am worried if I bind my snmp agent to INADDR_ANY, snmp agent will not listen and response well.

Comment: @zhaojing, INADDR_ANY means "listen on all IP addresses on this machine".

Comment: bstpierre, thanks for your explanations. Yes, I got the idea now. And your solution works, thanks ：-）